# Allow only one instance of a content type

Tags: admin, backend, bolt-cms, contenttype

I have created a custom content-type for the homepage in bolt. And I was wondering how to remove the "add new home" from the admin panel of bolt so that it is only possible for my client to have 1 instance of the homepage, instead being able to add multiple which would make no sense.

So essentially removing the that function that is called "New [name of contenttype] option.

I think this could be done by writing my own extension maybe but i'm not capable of doing this yet as I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking creating a whole new contenttype for home page isn't a good idea unless you want the user to have the ability to add more of those.

Anyways, you can restrict your user from adding more of home contenttypes through permissions.yml. As a first step, define roles e.g. superadmin is you who develops the system and admin is the user of CMS. Then for home contenttype, set `create` permission to superadmin:

```
`create: [ superadmin ]`
```

All of the other users won't be able to create new homes including admins.

More on this in bolt docs: https://docs.bolt.cm/permissions#example-editors-and-chief-editors

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In the time of posting my question and reading your comment i have in fact added my records for home back to the index and stepped away from the custom template.  This was as you are stating not a good idea. Thanks for the link in the bolt forms. I really starting to get the hang of yammel and twig. Starting to diving into the permissions docs.

Comment: Feel free to ping me when you have a bolt specific question. We have used bolt in on of a very critical projects recently that was going out of hands and literally built a quite sophisticated site in less than 4 hrs. Same would have taken us at least 80hrs with Wordpress.

Comment: Will do! I have build 3 sites so far and i can't ever go back to Wordpress after the 3rd site i build. Ive even accomplished making a comment system with boltforms. I am also building websites faster then it took using wordpress. More time for concepting and design.

Comment: The only reason I am going for Wordpress in my next project is because Bolt doesn't have support/integration for shopping cart / eCommerce. I am going for WooCommerce but would still want to go back to bolt anytime if I find a solution.

Comment: Yes then wp or another on the go shop is faster. But it is definitely possible. It would require some coding. But i cant see why there cant be an extension for it in bolt :)